# how to override 'public' privileges

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

As there are some databases on the server available for public role, how can I close access to database for sqlserver login directly? Login is not using database but has access under public privileges. I need to keep access for public but deny for user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A deny always take precedence over any grant. In order to be able to deny permission, you need a principal to apply the deny to. Therefore the sequence of actions is:

- create user for login in the database (so that you have a principal)
- explicitly deny permission to the user created above

Note that, as a rule, you cannot deny a permissions on a securable to the owner of that securable. Members of sysadmin are always mapped to dbo, hence they cannot be denied any permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the user under the Security node for the server (not the database) in SQL Server Management Studio, you can modify their permissions under the "Status" page (double click the username) and set "Permission to connect to database engine:" to `Deny` and "Login:" to `Disabled`